# Right panel behaviour - Bug or feature?

Tags: bug, design, editing

[image: img]

As you can can see on the image, right panel overlaps main white panel, if in "Edit answer" tab I scroll down. Is it a bug or feature?

Comment: Do you see this in other sites? If so, perhaps it's better to take this [tag:bug] to MSE

Comment: Anyways, I say it's a bug as it hides the Blog Facebook Twitter and LinkedIn links